# Formulating and solving a partial differential equation for an isotopy (i.e. bending deformation) of curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Imagine a piece of string in the ocean moving gently with the currents; the string bends but does not change its length.

The (stationary) string can be modelled by a unit speed curve:

$$[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$$

The motion of the string, say from time 0 to time 1, can be modelled by an *isotopy*:

$$\alpha : [0,1]^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$$

where $\alpha(-,0)$ and $\alpha(-,1)$ are the positions of the string at time 0 and time 1, respectively. To ensure that the length of the string is constant in the intermediate times, $\alpha$ must satisfy:

$$
\frac \partial {\partial t}  \left\lvert\frac {\partial \alpha} {\partial s}\right\rvert = 0
$$

equivalently:

$$
\frac {\partial \alpha} {\partial s}  \cdot \frac {\partial^2 \alpha} {\partial s \partial t} = 0
$$

Thinking of a deforming string, it is intuitively clear that an isotopy exists but is far from unique.

Question 1: What sort of extra conditions might be imposed that would guarantee the existence of a unique isotopy (assuming any reasonable differentiability conditions).

Question 2: How does one go about (numerically, I assume) solving such a system of equations?

Question 3:
As a partial answer to question 1, define a metric on the set of unit length curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The motion of the string is a path in this space. One could require that this path be of minimal in the sense that it follows a geodesic. I feel that such a minimal isotopy would be unique. What is an appropriate metric? Is there a simple equation that characterizes such paths (with respect to that metric)? How can I compute such a path, given the endpoints?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of to model your problem is to construct the Frenet frame for the curve, and allow the matrix entries $\kappa$ and $\tau$ in that model to become functions of $s$ and $t$. Integrating these equations provides the position vector. There are evidently many ways the curve can be deformed.

In order to impose additional features in your model (to get a possibly unique solution), you could try imposing a physical law describing the external and possible internal forces that act on each part of the object.  One choice  is that the acceleration is proportional to the curvature   vector: $\ddot \alpha = \kappa \vec n$. But if you are willing to abandon physical realism then the possibilities are endless. You could define the energy in the system at any moment to be the integral of the squared curvature, and insist that the  energy  decay roughly according to the heat equation, in the sense that the string evolves in the direction that dissipates energy fastest.

You might explore [this survey](https://www.math.toronto.edu/roberth/pde2/curve_shortening_flow.pdf) on the modeling of the evolution of curves using PDEs
and note in particular Proposition 1.17 therein.

Comment: Your modelling suggestion seems reasonable, but I don't see that it helps address the questions I posed. Specifically, what additional constraints can be imposed so that $\kappa$ and $\tau$ are uniquely determined and how then can they be computed?

Comment: A given metric determines geodesics, but for a given elastic line with arbitrary $(\tau, \kappa)$ there is no unique metric. If you take a twistie with arbitrary bending & twisting ,no  suitable metric can be found. If a  $f(\tau, \kappa) =0 $ is given or if these are constant some headway can be made to define an Elastica.

Comment: Apologies ... I think that I only noticed the first paragraph on my first reading.

Comment: If I interpolate curvature and torsion (linearly interpolate or otherwise) then I can (as I think you are suggesting) certainly reconstruct (up to a rigid motion) the intermediate curves. My problem still remains: how can I guarantee that those intermediate curves still have unit speed? The local speeds on the interpolated curves depends (unless I'm misunderstanding something) on the interpolation functions. How can those interpolation functions be chosen to achieve this?

Comment: The interpretation of the variable s is the arc length in all intermediate cases.

Comment: That's what I was hoping for. Can you explain why?

Comment: All of that is baked into the definition of the Frenet frame as unit-speed tangent vector and its derivatives wr.t. $s$=*arclength*.